# Jquery tabs border line to expand with div section content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

This allows me to display two divs side by side within the tab section, however the border line that surrounds the tabs doesn't conform to the content within the divs.  It doesn't expand correctly.  Anyone knows how to fix this?

aspx

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="first">
                sdfd<br />
                sdfdf</div>
            <div id="second"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

css

```
#container
{
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #ffcc33;
    margin: auto;
}
#first
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    /*height: 300px; */ /* take this out to work wit below solution*/
    background-color: blue;
}
#second
{
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
#clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

[image]

Comment: where is css for tabs? the css you shared so far works fine... if I understood the question correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/j7jxs8qm/

Comment: Sorry been messing around with it and assumed everyone knows this came from the jquery tabs ui. So I don't even specify tabs css in my own code.  How can I override this in the ui tabs without having to change the theme css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the tabs float as well

```
#tabs{
 float:left;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: weird it worked using the inline debugger at first then recompiled and check and it didn't work.  The final tag that worked along with this is taking the height:300px on the second menu. commenting out above.